# Several commands for installing another Desktop-Environment didn't help

Tags: command-line, desktop-environments

Very new to Ubuntu, I've tried to install two Desktop-Environments (KDE, Cinnamon) via several commands while as root user, after reading in Google how to do so but nothing helped... Here is the code. Please give me an advice,

```
ben@ben-X58-USB3:~$ su
Password: 
root@ben-X58-USB3:/home/ben# apt-get install kde_desktop
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package kde_desktop
root@ben-X58-USB3:/home/ben# apt-get install kde-standart
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package kde-standart
root@ben-X58-USB3:/home/ben# apt-get install kde_standart
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package kde_standart
root@ben-X58-USB3:/home/ben# apt-get install kde
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package kde is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'kde' has no installation candidate
root@ben-X58-USB3:/home/ben# apt-get install KDE
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package kde is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'kde' has no installation candidate
root@ben-X58-USB3:/home/ben# apt-get install KDE-standart
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package KDE-standart
root@ben-X58-USB3:/home/ben#
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To install KDE: `sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop`

Cinnamon `sudo apt-get install cinnamon-desktop-environment`

Here is an extensive list of desktop environments and commands to install them: [What kinds of desktop environments and shells are available?](https://askubuntu.com/q/65083/476968)

Comment: Much thanks! 1. If I work as root-user I guess I don't need sudo? 2. What is the meaning of kubuntu ? What is the k?

Comment: You’re welcome :).  Yes, I don’t think there is need to use `sudo` when you are already root(I could be wrong though :D). In my humble opinion, the K in Kubuntu stands for KDE desktop environment(KdeUbuntu),  in a same way that Xubuntu is Ubuntu with a  XFCE desktop environment(XfceUbuntu) and Lubuntu runs on  LXDE desktop environment(LxdeUbuntu).

Comment: Thank you so much! I would be glad to thumbs up your answer but I seem to look only 2 rep points to do so :)